# Create union type annotation from dynamically generated array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, union-types

Giving a generated array from a reduce, how is it possible to create a union type from this array?

```js
import someFancyObject from 'some/modules';
const generatedArray = someFancyObject.reduce((acc, val, i) => {...}, []);

// generatedArray would be like: ['a', 'b', 'c']

type UnionFromArray = ???

// UnionFromArray would be like 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible as typing happens statically, and you are trying to define this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can either infer an array from function argument or declare constant (immutable) array:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
type UnionFromArray = (typeof arr)[number] // "a" | "b" | "c"

// OR

const unionFromArray = <
  T extends string,
  Arr extends T[]
>(arr: [...Arr]): Arr[number] => null as any

const result = unionFromArray(['a', 'b', 'c']) // // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Comment: the array (['a', 'b', 'c'] is just an example) is generated dinamically by the reduce method. is not declared statically.

Comment: If it generegate dinamically, TS is unable to figure out the values. You can check them only in runtime